# Tension of rope in the gravitational field of earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

> Two balls of mass $m$ each one are connected with mass-less rope with
>   the same length as the radius of earth. The system is in free fall.
>   Prove that the tension of the rope when the nearest (to the earth)
>   ball's distance from the earth surface is $R_E/2$ is:  $T =
>  \frac{32}{225} mg$

[image: Illustration]

What I did is the following:

$F_1$ is a gravitation force exerted on the nearest ball by the earth: $F_1=G \frac{M_Em}{(1.5R_E)^2}$

$F_2$ is a gravitation force exerted on the farthest ball by the earth: $F_2=G \frac{M_E m}{(2.5R_E)^2}$

$T=F_1-F_2=G \frac{M_E m}{(1.5R_E)^2}-G \frac{M_E m}{(2.5R_E)^2}=\frac{G M_E m}{R_E^2} \left (\frac{4}{9} - \frac{4}{25} \right)=\frac{64}{225} mg$

However, my answer is somehow twice bigger than what is expected. Where am I wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Consider the acceleration of each ball in terms of the forces and tension. The two balls should have the same acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotcha covered:

$$F_1=G{M_E m\over(1.5R_E)^2}\mathbf {-T}$$ -T from upwards force of rope.
$$F_2=G{M_Em\over(2.5R_E)^2}\mathbf {+T}$$ +T from downwards force of rope.

Then since the rope isn't stretching,

$$F_1~=~F_2$$
$$2T~=~G{M_E m\over(1.5R_E)^2}-G{M_Em\over(2.5R_E)^2}~=~{64\over225}mg$$
$$\therefore~T~=~{32\over225}mg$$

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I now see how my question was stupid! But why you say that 'rope isn't stretching'? I thought $F_1=F_2$ is because $F_1=ma$ and $F_2=ma$.

Comment: it's taut, but the length isn't changing, that's what I meant.